Unable to connect to MongoDB from Python: ServerSelectionTimeoutError raised
A ServerSelectionTimeoutError is raised. I don't know why though.
This is the script that I am trying to run just to check the connection to the db is working.

connection_string = "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster.xxxxxx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=appName"

client = MongoClient(connection_string)

db = client.books

print(db.list_collection_names())

client.close()

However this code raises a ServerSelectionTimeoutError.

C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe C:\\Users\\fastf\\PycharmProjects\\cm2110-2023-24-coursework-toast-board\\Devices\\Master\\mongoTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\PycharmProjects\\cm2110-2023-24-coursework-toast-board\\Devices\\Master\\mongoTest.py", line 9, in \<module\>
print(db.list_collection_names())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\database.py", line 1147, in list_collection_names
return \[result\["name"\] for result in self.list_collections(session=session, \*\*kwargs)\]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\database.py", line 1099, in list_collections
return self.\__client.\_retryable_read(\_cmd, read_pref, session)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py", line 1492, in \_retryable_read
return self.\_retry_internal(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo_csot.py", line 107, in csot_wrapper
return func(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py", line 1462, in \_retry_internal
).run()
^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py", line 2315, in run
return self.\_read() if self.\_is_read else self.\_write()
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py", line 2437, in \_read
self.\_server = self.\_get_server()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py", line 2400, in \_get_server
return self.\_client.\_select_server(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\mongo_client.py", line 1303, in \_select_server
server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\topology.py", line 302, in select_server
server = self.\_select_server(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\topology.py", line 286, in \_select_server
servers = self.select_servers(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\topology.py", line 237, in select_servers
server_descriptions = self.\_select_servers_loop(selector, server_timeout, address)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\fastf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymongo\\topology.py", line 259, in \_select_servers_loop
raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-00.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net:27017: \[WinError 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-01.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net:27017: \[WinError 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-02.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net:27017: \[WinError 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: \<TopologyDescription id: 661945ce46ec5a4462528732, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: \[\<ServerDescription ('ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-00.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-00.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net:27017: \[WinError 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')\>, \<ServerDescription ('ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-01.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-01.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net:27017: \[WinError 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')\>, \<ServerDescription ('ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-02.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-9pd9kw6-shard-00-02.sd1ix5k.mongodb.net:27017: \[WinError 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')\>\]\>

Process finished with exit code 1

I tried I think almost all solutions online but still not working. I didn't want to create a certificated user, I tried that, and still didn't work.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

